# Capture Motor Pulse and Modify

Tags: motor, flipflop

I have a piece of equipment that pulses a 4.5V motor for a 500ms forward, then 500ms backwards.  I have no control over the board creating this function; however, I want to modify the signal to only pulse forward on the first action, and backward on the next.  Therefore, I want to intercept the wires going to the motor and create a small project that can achieve this.  I have tried to bread board a single latch relay to flip flop the signal; yet, my pea brain cannot get around the logic to make it work correctly.  I have also tried to draw up a schematic with a dual coil latch relay, and no luck.  I understand this is a broad question, yet I have googled this to death and have found no where to start.

**Edited:**
Signal coming from the controller are pulses of (4.5v 500ms -4.5v 500ms) each **triggered event**.  I want (4.5v ~500ms) first trigger event and then next pulse (-4.5v ~500ms) next trigger event and reset to first.

Comment: so what are you modifying? from what i read you don't seem to change anything.

Comment: I am eliminating the trailing reverse pulse from the first, and removing the forward pulse from the next.